# Executing function of parent window in the context of a child window

Tags: javascript, parent-child, clipboard, window.open

I'm attempting to design a web page that uses `window.open` to spawn a child window, then register a clickable button within that window to copy a text payload to the user's clipboard. Specifically, I'm using [clipboard.js](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/) to register the button, but I'm having difficulties getting it to work within the child window. My code so far is roughly as follows:

```
var payloadWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=800, height=600, scrollbars=yes");
var button = payloadWindow.document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button";
button.value = "Copy to Clipboard";
button.id = "copyToClipboard";
payloadWindow.document.body.appendChild(button);
payloadWindow.document.body.appendChild(payloadTextNode); // payloadTextNode already declared
var clipboard = new Clipboard("#" + button.id, {
  text: function() {
    return payloadText; // payloadText already declared
  }
});
```

This works in so far as the window appears and contains both the button and the payload text, but the button is not registered with any handlers, and does not react to mouse clicks.

The problem, as far as I understand, is that the `Clipboard` constructor is being called in a script that was loaded by the parent window. So when it searches for buttons with the id `copyToClipboard`, it's actually searching the parent window for elements when I need it to search the child window. I've verified this by stepping through `clipboard.js` (v1.5.12) with the debugger and reaching this statement on line 208:

```
return delegate(document.body, selector, type, callback);
```

`document.body` upon inspection, refers to the body of the parent window, so it seems that `Clipboard` is indeed searching for `button` in the "wrong" place.

So my question, in a more concise form, is:

Is there any way to force a function called from window `A` to execute in the context of window `B`? I essentially want to be able to do this:

```
(function(payloadText) {
  var clipboard = new Clipboard("#" + button.id, {
    text: function() {
      return payloadText; // payloadText already declared
    }
}).callFrom(payloadWindow, payloadText);
```

With `callFrom` representing some function that would let me execute the lambda function with `payloadWindow` as its global context. If this is impossible, is there an idiomatic way to emulate this functionality? I would like to be able to pass the payload text directly from the parent window to the child window if possible, without routing through a controller.

Comment: Try replacing `"#" + button.id` with `payloadWindow.document.getElementById(button.id)`.

Comment: @imtheman Thank you, I tried your suggestion and `Clipboard` threw the following exception: `Uncaught TypeError: First argument must be a String, HTMLElement, HTMLCollection, or NodeList`

Comment: Bummer. I'll keep thinking. That makes it a lot harder though...

Comment: Yes, it's a tricky problem. I appreciate your willingness to help. From what I've experienced banging my head against this, I'm leaning towards trying to get the child window to execute a script directly, which could then possibly read the payload text from `window.opener`. I'm having trouble, however, getting the Chrome debugger to hook into scripts run from the child window, possibly because it was created through `window.open`?

Comment: I think the best option would be to put the Clipboard script in the popup window.